# Update Listbox without restarting program?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I'm building an WinForms application which is going to be an adressbook. I'm stuck with a problem though. When I open the program and press on my load contacts button, it loads all that's written in the txt file. But if I create a new contact and press load again, the new contact doesn't show up. Is there any way to fix this?

Also, when I try to create new methods for example a `Delete()` method. It says "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." Any ideas why is crashes?

```
    List<string> Load()
    {
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(path);
        string row = "";
        while ((row = read.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            adressbook.Add(row);
        }
        read.Close();
        return adressbook; //Adressbook is my List<string> adressbook = new List<string> uptop.
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list = Load();
        listBox1.DataSource = list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set to *null* the *DataSource* before clearing and binding:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.DataSource != null)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    List<string> list = Load();
    listBox1.DataSource = list;
}
```

In your *Load* you must first clear the list

```
List<string> Load()
{
    if (adressbook.Count != 0)
    {
        adressbook.Clear();
    }

    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(path);
    string row = "";
    while ((row = read.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        adressbook.Add(row);
    }
    read.Close();
    return adressbook; //Adressbook is my List<string> adressbook = new List<string> uptop.
}
```

Comment: When doing this and creating a new contact then loading again, I get an update with the new contact, though I get the new contact plus the old one. So my listbox looks like "Fredrik" -- New contact "Boris" -- Update: "Fredrik, Fredrik Boris".